# POST 400 bad request in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am integrating an angularjs with nodejs now i got an error in browser.http 400 bad requset.I want to know is it front end error or back end error and i need solution.

register.html

```
      <form class="register-form" name="myRegisterForm" ng-hide="login" ng-submit="register(user)" novalidate>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name" name="username" minlength="5" maxlength="25"/>
        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="myRegisterForm.username.$error.minlength">Given Name should be above 5 letters.</span><br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number" ng-model="user.phone" name="phonenum"
               minlength="10" maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9-]*$/" required/>
        <span style="color:red"  ng-style="{'padding-top':'2px'}" ng-show="myRegisterForm.phonenum.$error.pattern">Please enter numbers only.</span>
        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="myRegisterForm.phonenum.$error.minlength">Phone number must be 10 digits .</span><br/>
        <input type="text" name=email placeholder="Email address" ng-model="user.email"
               ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/" required/>
        <span style="color:red" ng-style="{'padding-top':'2px'}" ng-show="myRegisterForm.email.$error.pattern">Please enter correct mail id</span><br/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" minlength="8" maxlength="16"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" ng-model="user.cpassword" minlength="8" maxlength="16"/>
        <span style="color:red" ng-style="{'padding-top':'2px'}" ng-show="user.password !== user.cpassword">Password is not match</span>
        <textarea placeholder="Address" ng-model="user.address"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
        <p class="message">Already registered? <p></form>
```

register.js

```
 $scope.register = function (user) {
    var data = {
        "user" : {
            "name": user.name,
            "email": user.email,
            "phone": "+91"+ user.phone,
            "password": user.password,
            "address": user.address

        }

    };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: data
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        if (response.data) {
            sharedServices.set(response.data);
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        if (response) {
            $scope.message = response.data;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: you gotta post the code man we have nothing to go by. welcome to SO

Comment: 400 Bad Request is sent by the server because the request format is invalid.

Comment: You have a blank url, is that correct?

Comment: ya in that url we use Api url.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Wikipedia's [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error):

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> The ***server*** cannot or will not process the request due to an
> apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).[36]

In layman's terms, `data` is invalid:

```
var data = {
  "user" : {
    "name": user.name,
    "email": user.email,
    "phone": "+91"+ user.phone,
    "password": user.password,
    "address": user.address
  }
};
```

When the server tries to process `data` it detects that `data` is invalid and sends a `400`.

Here are some **possible** causes:

- `data` is missing a required value
- `data.phone` is invalid
- `data.address` is invalid
- `data.password` is invalid (maybe it's too weak...?)
- An important request `header` is missing

You should check that the format of `data` matches what the server expects.

You should also check the response body to see if it contains a more specific error.

Comment: data is valid because i got exact output of name,email,phone,address.now i got an error password field is missing.

Comment: @BalaDev I updated my answer with some more details. I hope that helps.

Comment: yes. now I got answer. its working perfectly. Thank u @ alex booker

Comment: @BalaDev Nice one. Please consider making my answer as accepted if it helped at all. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about this, but I am facing a similar problem, in that I am getting an HTTP 400 when I post data using my ngResource service and get a proper response when I post the same request JSON through APIView in Django. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I solved this issue by changing

```
data: {}
```

to

```
params: {}
```